# I have 750 million people that belong into 750 categories. How many people do I have to randomly sample to get an idea for distribution?

Tags: probability, sampling

Total people = 750M
Number of groups = 750

I have no additional information, and am looking to do a random sampling of the group. Assume everyone will respond with correct information on which group they are in. How many people would I have to randomly poll to get an accurate percentage breakdown for how many people are in a given group?

Comment: I think you can’t estimate any sample size without you having a prior hypothesis on the proportions of subjects within each group. Also, you are dealing with very large numbers, so I guess your are sampling just because you don’t know how to deal with the entire dataset. Am I correct?

Comment: You need to define accurate, but then consider this case: Imagine one of the 750 groups has a single person in it. How many people do you need to sample to get an accurate estimate of the proportion in that group?